# Get first day of last month in Java HSQL database

Tags: sql, date, hsqldb

How can I select first day of last month and last day of next month in HSQL database?

I tried it postgres way like follows:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', current_date - INTERVAL '1 month') :: DATE AS first_day_of_last_month;
```

Does not work in Java HSQL database thou. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the LAST_DAY(date) function.

```
LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE - 2 MONTH) + 1 DAY

LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE + 1 MONTH)
```